# Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:35229/angular2/platform/browser

Tags: angular, typescript

I have write a small program in visual studios 2013 for angular2/typescript its running on all browser fine.. but when i run it on `INTERNET EXPLORER` i just get nothing...  when i `inspect element` i get the following errors

```
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:35229/angular2/platform/browser

Error loading http://localhost:35229/angular2/platform/browser as "angular2/platform/browser" from http://localhost:35229/js/main.ts
```

my main.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS ] );
```

Comment: which angular version you are using ? In latest angular `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` is deprecated.

Comment: angular2 version... then what should i use..

Comment: check Routing tutorial from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html